# Pandas get subtract of value between hours

Tags: python, pandas

I have DataFrame:

```
date, time, value
2019-06-03, 15:30:00, 5131
2019-06-03, 15:45:00, 5142
2019-06-03, 16:00:00, 5135
2019-06-04, 15:30:00, 5134
2019-06-04, 15:45:00, 5138
2019-06-04, 16:00:00, 5148
```

i need data like: how many dates is on plus/minus(value) between time like [15:30:00-16:00:00], iterate by all possible hours

output example:
[15:30:00 - 16:00:00] 2 rows on plus // because 1st date: 5135-5131=4 / 2nd date 5148-5134=14

Comment: please provide the exact expected output

Answer (score 0):

You could convert your dates in seconds and then do

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(yourData)
start = df["Seconds"] >= lowerSeconds
end = df["Seconds"] <= upperSeconds
dates_between_start_and_end = df[start & end]
# => all Values are Nan. except those in range of [lowerSeconds, upperSeconds]
```

I could imagine that there is a way to do the same claculation with Date objects

Comment: 'on plus' i mean value